# Add Vercel Environment Variable that points to JSON file

Tags: json, environment-variables, google-cloud-storage, credentials, vercel

How to add a secret file in a secure location on a Vercel deployment server?

I am deploying a Next.js project to Vercel. The project is an uploader connected to Google Cloud Platform. It uploads files to a storage bucket.

Locally the file works fine. Credentials for GCP are stored in a local JSON file, as supplied by GPC (created automatically when the credentials are created). I am using the .env file to store environment variables, including the path to this local file.

On Vercel, I will need to supply an environment variable as well that supplies a path to this json file. Where can I store this JSON file on the Vercel deployment server?

Using the cli I have tried:

```
vercel secrets add GOOGLE_CLOUD_KEY_FILE --json path/to/file.json
```

and

```
vercel secrets add GOOGLE_CLOUD_KEY_FILE --local-file path/to/file.json
```

Which don't work. The cli returns an error about too many arguments. In any case these options are not documented.

Also I checked the docs and the dashboard for a way to add a secret, without success.

Comment: Is there an answer to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to get around this is to pass in a string to env variable and then parse it in your code as JSON.

1. Remove line breaks (except any that are inside "". maybe part of a key.) from the json file. I've used [textfiler](https://www.textfixer.com/tools/remove-line-breaks.php) in
   the past.
2. Create a new Vercel environment variable. To do this via the command line, run `vercel env add SECRET_JSON`. It will prompt you `? What’s the value of SECRET_JSON?`. You can paste the json content from step 1. You can also do this via  the [Vercel web ui](https://vercel.com/docs/environment-variables). If you are developing locally, you can add it like this `SECRET_JSON='JSON file content without line breaks'` to your `.env.local`
3. Use the new env variable by parsing it as json. `const secretJSON = JSON.parse( process.env.SECRET_JSON);`